# Turning Python ndarray into dataframe with added index

Tags: python, pandas

I have obtained the aggregated results from a dataframe using `groupby()`, which returns me an ndarray that looks like this:

```
                   attendanceStrikes
Name                                
John Doe                         0.0
Jane Doe                         0.0
Will Myers                       0.0
```

How do I turn this into a data frame with two columns - one containing the "Name", the other containing the "attendanceStrikes"?

Comment: provide `as_index=False` when you do `groupby` so that the grouped key doesn't become the index axis later.

Comment: thanks @NickilMaveli, that did the job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `result` is the Series that you have after groupby `result.reset_index()` should be the dataframe you want.